# how do I configure compute resources that can write to blob storage in azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

my apologies as I'm very new to azure.

I am working on a startup and I'm using some free credits on the consumption plan for now to do some prototyping.

My goal is to allocate some infrastructure for a web app that will read/write from/to blob storage for certain data.

My thinking was that it would be easier/faster to use a Web App than a general purpose vm, so I created one (Linux). But under Configuration->Path Mappings when I click learn more it says that blob storage can only be read-only - but I need write access too. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=basic%2Cportal&pivots=container-linux)

What I could try: use a vm instead of a web app...
Note that I don't want to run Windows, I prefer linux.

Are there better ways to approach this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Path Mappings are for read-only access, while direct SDK/API usage enables complete read/write capabilities in Azure App Service.

**Direct Interaction (Read and Write)**

Azure App Service can fully interact with Azure Blob Storage using Azure Storage SDKs or REST APIs, which provide functionalities like uploading, updating, and deleting blobs.

**Path Mappings (Read-Only Access)**

In Azure App Service, mounting Blob storage using Path Mappings is read-only. Similar to a DVD drive, you can read files but cannot write using regular system write operations.

**TL;DR**: Use Azure Storage SDKs (`Install-Package Azure.Storage.Blobs`) or REST APIs in your code for writing.

```cs
var connectionString = "YourStorageAccountConnectionString";
var containerName = "your-container-name";
var blobName = "example.txt";
var content = "Hello, Azure Blob Storage!";

var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, overwrite: true);
```

[Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what path mapping are for! Appreciated!